# Multilevel Modeling: Minimization Problem when A = B + TCT'

Tags: multilevel-analysis, matrix, linear-algebra

I currently study multilevel model using Leeuw & Meijer (2008) Handbook of multilevel analysis. On page 65, they state the following theorem:

If $A = B + TCT'$ with $A$ and $B$ positive definite, then

$y'A^{-1}y = \displaystyle \min_{x}{(y-Tx)'B^{-1}(y-Tx) + x'C^{-1}x}$.

The proof has been given in [Majorization Algorithms for Mixed Model Analysis](http://gifi.stat.ucla.edu/janspubs/1993/reports/deleeuw_liu_R_93.pdf) by Leeuw & Liu (1993; p. 17). They state to proof a slightly more general result:

$\displaystyle \min_{x}{(y-Tx)'D(y-Tx) + x'Ex}$

with $D$ and $E$ positive definite. As they highlight, the minimum is attained for any x that solves

$(T'DT + E)x = T'Dy$.

The minimum is therefore equal to

$y'[D - DT(T'DT + E)^+TD]y$

where $^{+}$ indicates the pseudoinverse. Thus, they conclude that

$A = [D-DT(T'DT + E)^+TD]^{-1}$.

I understand each and every step of the proof but I am not sure what they try to prove. They want to show that ${(y-Tx)'D(y-Tx) + x'E^{-1}x}$ is minimized when $A = [D-DT(T'DT + E)^+TD]^{-1}$.

However, what justifies using ${(y-Tx)'D(y-Tx) + x'E^{-1}x}$ as the starting point. In there any fundamental relationship between

$y'A^{-1}y$

and

${(y-Tx)'D(y-Tx) + x'E^{-1}x}$

that justifies this starting point?

Comment: I emailed the authors of the paper. They responded: "the proof is obviously truncated and incomplete. It aims to generalize the result in the lemma to positive semi-definite B and C, but it is far yet from doing this." Not to sure what to make of this. Also, if a publication quotes another paper to justify a result they are using but this paper presented a proof that is "truncated and incomplete" then do we have a proof?